# How do you inherit a TableLayoutPanel and default it to one column

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, tablelayoutpanel, column-count

I am attempting to inherit a tablelayoutpanel and set a custom amount of rows and columns.

I found some code that allows this to be done.

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLayout(ByVal levent As LayoutEventArgs)
    Me.ColumnCount = 4
    Me.RowCount = 4
    MyBase.OnLayout(levent)
    End Sub
```

However when I change the code so that the columncount or rowcount is 1 then I get an index out of range when dropping the control onto the form.

Is there anything that I am missing that would allow this to work?

Comment: I think that you should do some reading about the exact meaning of "inheriting". Here you have a link to start with: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yk8s7sk.aspx

Comment: may be it has to do with `Me.ColumnsStyles` and `Me.RowStyles`